# Executing .py file also runs another .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three files in one dir:

```
# Untitled-1.py

print("UTITLEDPY")

if __name__== "__main__":
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, InlineQueryHandler
    import logging
    from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, InlineQueryResultPhoto, InputTextMessageContent
```

and

```
# test.py
import google_image_search

print("TESTPY")
```

and this one

```
# google_image_search.py

print("IMAGESPY")
```

When I run `python3 Untitled-1.py`, I have the following output:

```
UTITLEDPY
IMAGESPY
TESTPY
```

Please, explain why. The expected output is `UTITLEDPY` only.

**[EDIT]**

I added `raise ValueError()` to `test.py`:

```
# test.py
import google_image_search

print("TESTPY")

raise ValueError()
```

After that running `python3 Untitled-1.py` gives the following output:

```
UTITLEDPY
IMAGESPY
TESTPY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled-1.py", line 5, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, InlineQueryHandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .files.file import File
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/files/file.py", line 24, in <module>
    from future.backports.urllib import parse as urllib_parse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/backports/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import_top_level_modules()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 810, in import_top_level_modules
    with exclude_local_folder_imports(*TOP_LEVEL_MODULES):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 781, in __enter__
    module = __import__(m, level=0)
  File "/Users/arturzielinski/Desktop/ibodi_bot/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

**[EDIT2]**

Renaming `test.py` to `test1.py` solved the issue. I now get the expected output.

Comment: Do some of the imports in `Untitled-1.py` go on to import your other two files?

Comment: I don't see any reason the other modules should be executed. Are there any imports you are not showing us?

Comment: Note that ``test`` might shadow the [``test`` builtin module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) which could be imported by something else.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi While that *might* be. It is unlikely `google_image_search` is imported by the imports shown.

Comment: If you don't want these files to be run when imported, why not wrap the code also with `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Comment: Could you raise an exception (for example `raise ValueError()`) after one of the undesired prints and post the full traceback?

Comment: can you show output of `cat Untitled-1.py`. ? :-) lol

Comment: @KlausD. ``google_image_search`` is imported by the custom ``test``. If any module attempts to import the original ``test``, it will instead import the custom ``test`` and in turn ``google_image_search``.

Comment: @KlausD. I followed your advice, the traceback of ValueError() is added to the question.

Comment: @KlausD. Renaming test.py to test1.py solved the issue. I now get the expected output.

Comment: -10 Python Zen points for the less beautiful and traceable imports in the telegram library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming `test.py` to `test1.py` solved the issue. I now get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is that `TOP_LEVEL_MODULES` from https://python-future.org/_modules/future/standard_library.html imports test. Which happens to collide with your file that takes precedence.

```
TOP_LEVEL_MODULES = ['builtins',
                 'copyreg',
                 'html',
                 'http',
                 'queue',
                 'reprlib',
                 'socketserver',
                 'test',
                 'tkinter',
                 'winreg',
                 'xmlrpc',
                 '_dummy_thread',
                 '_markupbase',
                 '_thread',
                ]
```